# How to return the generators in a monomial in Sage?

Tags: math-software, sagemath

Let $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n$ be symbols. Are there some functions in Sage which return the generators in a monomial? For example, I would like to have a function $f$ such that $f(s3*s4*s2)=[s3,s4,s2]$. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does sorting of the resulting list matter?

Comment: Don't consider this as an answer but using a loop you can check the degree of a symbol $s_i$ in a monomial $f$ by $f.$degree$(s_i)$ and  see if this is nonzero. In this case you can form the list by appending every symbol with a nonzero degree.

Comment: @Levent, thank you very much. Sorting of the resulting list doesn't matter.

Comment: No problem, I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it is in a symbolic expression or in a polynomial,
the `.variables()` method should work.

Example with a symbolic expression:

```
sage: s = SR.var(['s{}'.format(i) for i in range(8)])
sage: s
(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7)
sage: r = lambda x: randint(0, 2)
sage: expr = sum([r()*prod(s[j]^r()) for j in range(8)) for _ in range(5)])
sage: expr
2*s0^2*s1^2*s2^2*s4^2*s5^2*s6^2*s7^2 + 2*s0*s1^2*s2*s3*s5*s6^2*s7^2 +
s0^2*s4^2*s5*s6^2*s7^2 + s0^2*s1*s2^2*s3^2*s7^2 + 2*s1*s2^2*s3^2*s5*s6^2
sage: monomials = expr.operands()
sage: monomials
[2*s0^2*s1^2*s2^2*s4^2*s5^2*s6^2*s7^2,
 2*s0*s1^2*s2*s3*s5*s6^2*s7^2,
 s0^2*s4^2*s5*s6^2*s7^2,
 s0^2*s1*s2^2*s3^2*s7^2,
 2*s1*s2^2*s3^2*s5*s6^2*s7]
sage: for m in monomials:
....:     print m.variables()
....:
(s0, s1, s2, s4, s5, s6, s7)
(s0, s1, s2, s3, s5, s6, s7)
(s0, s4, s5, s6, s7)
(s0, s1, s2, s3, s7)
(s1, s2, s3, s5, s6, s7)
```

Example with a polynomial.

```
sage: R = PolynomialRing(QQ, 8, 's')
sage: R
Multivariate Polynomial Ring in s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7 over Rational Field
sage: s = R.gens()
sage: s
(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7)
sage: r = lambda x: randint(0, 2)
sage: poly = sum([r()*prod(s[j]^r() for j in range(8)) for _ in range(5)])
sage: poly
s0*s1^2*s2^2*s4*s5^2*s6^2 + 3*s1*s5^2*s6^2*s7
sage: monomials = poly.monomials()
sage: monomials
[s0*s1^2*s2^2*s4*s5^2*s6^2, s1*s5^2*s6^2*s7]
sage: for m in monomials:
....:     print m.variables()
....:
(s0, s1, s2, s4, s5, s6)
(s1, s5, s6, s7)
```